# How to use will_paginate with json parsed data that comes from HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, will-paginate, httparty

I am wondering how to use will_paginate on JSON data that comes from HTTPparty

In the api call, I can specify which page number to get and limit per page. 
At the bottom of each page, I want to be able to paginate and show next results. So for example when a user clicks next or "2", it will display next results from the json api data.

Controller:

```
@limit ||= 10
@dir = params[:sort] || 'asc'
@page ||= 1
response = HTTParty.get("http://api.whatever.com/shop/api/rest/products?page=#{@page}&limit=#{@limit}&order=name&dir=#{@dir}")
@parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

View:

```
#products
  - @parsed_response.each do |id, product|
    .box.panel.panel-default
      = link_to image_tag(product['image_url']), controller: "products", action: "show", :id => product["id"]
      .panel-body
        .product_name= link_to product['name'], controller: "products", action: "show", :id => product["id"]
        .product_description= link_to product['description'].html_safe, controller: "products", action: "show", :id => product["id"]
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @iamse7en Sorry I don't remember. I have stopped using Ruby On Rails and do JavaScript/PHP stack now.

Comment: no worries, i figured it out. thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663682/will-paginate-json-array