# will_paginate JSON array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, will-paginate

Decided to JSONify with Redis my site. How do I get `will_paginate` to work with json?

```
# games.html.erb
<%= js_will_paginate @games, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails, class: 'pagination-sm', previous_label: "&#8592;".html_safe, next_label: "&#8594;".html_safe, page_links: false %>
```

This is the error I get:

```
# undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x007f90ebc05cf0> ln 23 of will_paginate_helper.rb
ln23: will_paginate(collection, options.merge(:renderer => WillPaginateHelper::WillPaginateJSLinkRenderer))
```

And my will_paginate_helper:

```
# will_paginate_helper.rb
module WillPaginateHelper
  class WillPaginateJSLinkRenderer < BootstrapPagination::Rails
    def prepare(collection, options, template)
      options[:params] ||= {}
      options[:params]['_'] = nil
      super(collection, options, template)
    end

    protected
    def link(text, target, attributes = {})
      if target.is_a? Fixnum
        attributes[:rel] = rel_value(target)
        target = url(target)
      end

      @template.link_to(target, attributes.merge(remote: true)) do
        text.to_s.html_safe
      end
    end
  end

  def js_will_paginate(collection, options = {})
    will_paginate(collection, options.merge(:renderer => WillPaginateHelper::WillPaginateJSLinkRenderer))
  end
end
```

when I play around with the cli below the nomethoderror exception...

```
>>  collection
=> [{"id"=>8199, "start_time"=>nil, "game_date"=>"2016-10-23", ... etc }]
>> collection.first
=> {"id"=>8199, "start_time"=>nil, ... etc
```

Do I need to convert `collection` to something will_paginate can work with or do I re-write/override `js_will_paginate`? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

added `require 'will_paginate/array'` to my `will_paginate_helper.rb` and then paginated the collection AFTER `.to_json`, e.g. in my helper (or your controller):

```
games = Game.order(game_date: :desc).postgame.to_json
@games = Oj.load games
@games = @games.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

Works with will_paginate or js_will_paginate just as before.